# Ionic command not found depois de atualizar

Tags: ionic, npm, cordova-plugin

Ontem quando fui abrir meu projeto ionic o terminal pediu pra atualizar, dei sim e depois disso parou de funcionar. Nao encontrava o diretorio ou algo do tipo, pesquisando no stack eu vi uma solução que dizia o problema estava no ionic -g root estar retornando o node_modules da pasta de usuarios e nao da global. Então a soluçao era fazer o comando npm config set prefix usr/local, fiz isso e piorou agora nao reconhece mais o ionic(bash: ionic: command not found) Parece que esse usr/local era pra mac ou linux. Como reverter isso? e qual seria o npm config set prefix correto pro windows 10? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Opa Daniel!

Estava com o mesmo problema.
Resolvi com:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic cordova

npm cache clean

npm install -g ionic cordova --save
```

Espero que resolva.

Answer (score 0):

Olá Daniel e Spaceman.

Também passei pelo mesmo problema, ai tentei fazer o que o Spaceman indicou mas não tive sucesso, pois para funcionar tive que desinstalar o node e instalar novamente e utilizar --force no comando npm cache clean, então ficou deste modo o passa a passo:

1) Desinstalar Node

2) Instalar Node (Caso não funcione tente reiniciar o computador antes)

3) npm uninstall -g ionic cordova (no terminal, rodando como adm)

4) npm cache clean --force (no terminal, rodando como adm)

5) npm install -g ionic cordova --save (no terminal, rodando como adm)

OBS: Um dos motivos do erro é por que sua máquina perdeu a referência com o node e o java, então para que funciona não esqueça de instalar antes de tudo o jdk do java [aqui](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt)